# How to sort XML in given order? (messing with exported iTunes playlists)

Tags: xml, xslt, itunes

In iTunes, when you export a playlist in XML it automatically exports it in a way where it is sorted by "date added" rather than the order the user orders it. Towards the end of the XML file, it lists the order of the playlist the user orders it by Song ID like this:

```
<key>Playlist Items</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>5365</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>5317</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>5235</integer>
                </dict>
            <array>
```

I transformed the XML document using this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Artist</th>
                <th>Year</th>

            </tr>
            <xsl:call-template name="records" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="records">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/dict[1]/dict">
            <xsl:element name="tr">
                <xsl:call-template name="songs" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="songs">

        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::* = 'Track ID']" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::* = 'Name']" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="child::*[preceding-sibling::* = 'Artist']" />
        </td>

        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I want to know how can I edit my XSL to transform my playlist to reorder everything according to the user-given order that appears at the end of the original XML file rather than by "date added"?**

EDIT - adding more of the original XML. Here is the snippet that pertains to the XSL thing I did:

```
<key>5189</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>5189</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>varsity jacket</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>bayou</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>3532008</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>220107</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2015-07-26T14:04:34Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2015-07-26T14:04:17Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>128</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3520959994</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2015-07-29T00:26:34Z</date>
            <key>Skip Count</key><integer>2</integer>
            <key>Skip Date</key><date>2015-08-29T05:12:33Z</date>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>BE57D36AF01737E3</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>Location</key><string>file:///Users/jason/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/bayou/Unknown%20Album/varsity%20jacket.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question to show a more representative sample of the input XML? Ideally one with some songs in! Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing! You can see that in the XSL I only use 3 things and scrap the rest in the transform.  I also added more in the example about the first bit of XML.

Comment: "*according to the user-given order that appears at the end of the original XML file*" I don't see anything like that in your XML. Please post a minimal, but **complete** example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essential, but friendly suggestion to your code: do not use `xsl:call-template` with a context if you can suffice with `xsl:apply-templates`, as it will limit your flow and complicates your code.

See my edits. I took your structure, but simplified by removing `xsl:call-template`, which served no additional purpose.

To sort, just use `xsl:sort` as child of `xsl:apply-templates`. Here I sort by name of the artist. You can add more sort keys if you want by adding more `xsl:sort` elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

     <!-- from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432619/how-to-sort-xml-in-given-order-messing-with-exported-itunes-playlists -->

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Artist</th>
                <th>Year</th>

            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/dict[1]/dict" >
                <!-- sort by value of the name of the song -->
                <xsl:sort select="key[. = 'Name']/following-sibling::*[1]" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dict">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dict/key[. = 'Track ID' or . = 'Name' or . = 'Artist']">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]" />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ignore what we do not need -->
    <xsl:template match="dict/*" priority="-1" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Since you didn't give valid XML as source document (it had two root elements), so I invented my own that fit your original code (i.e., that actually output something) and added a second record to make sure the sorting worked. A friendly suggestion, if you ask XSLT questions in the future, it will make it easier for us if you include a (minimal) source document that we can use to test fixes to your code.

The new source doc:

```
<root>
    <record>
        <dict>
            <key>5189</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>5189</integer>
                <key>Name</key><string>varsity jacket</string>
                <key>Artist</key><string>bayou</string>
                <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
                <key>Size</key><integer>3532008</integer>
                <key>Total Time</key><integer>220107</integer>
                <key>Date Modified</key><date>2015-07-26T14:04:34Z</date>
                <key>Date Added</key><date>2015-07-26T14:04:17Z</date>
                <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>128</integer>
                <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
                <key>Play Count</key><integer>1</integer>
                <key>Play Date</key><integer>3520959994</integer>
                <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2015-07-29T00:26:34Z</date>
                <key>Skip Count</key><integer>2</integer>
                <key>Skip Date</key><date>2015-08-29T05:12:33Z</date>
                <key>Persistent ID</key><string>BE57D36AF01737E3</string>
                <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
                <key>Location</key><string>file:///Users/jason/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/bayou/Unknown%20Album/varsity%20jacket.mp3</string>
                <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
                <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>5190</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>5190</integer>
                <key>Name</key><string>some song</string>
                <key>Artist</key><string>anton</string>
                <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
                <key>Size</key><integer>3532008</integer>
                <key>Total Time</key><integer>220107</integer>
                <key>Date Modified</key><date>2015-07-26T14:04:34Z</date>
                <key>Date Added</key><date>2015-07-26T14:04:17Z</date>
                <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>128</integer>
                <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
                <key>Play Count</key><integer>1</integer>
                <key>Play Date</key><integer>3520959994</integer>
                <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2015-07-29T00:26:34Z</date>
                <key>Skip Count</key><integer>2</integer>
                <key>Skip Date</key><date>2015-08-29T05:12:33Z</date>
                <key>Persistent ID</key><string>BE57D36AF01737E3</string>
                <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
                <key>Location</key><string>file:///Users/jason/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Music/bayou/Unknown%20Album/varsity%20jacket.mp3</string>
                <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>4</integer>
                <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </record>
</root>
```

And the new sorted-by-name output:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Year</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5190</td>
      <td>some song</td>
      <td>anton</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5189</td>
      <td>varsity jacket</td>
      <td>bayou</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Also note: your first snippet has `array/dict`, your second snippet only had `dict`, but your XSLT uses `dict/dict`, so I changed the source structure such that it fit your XSLT code.

---

You said:

> *sort [...] according to the user-given order that appears at the end of the original XML file rather than by "date added"*

You'll need to expand on the example I gave above. Since I do not know the structure of the XML with regards to this part, and it was not given in the question, I couldn't apply it. However, I assume it will be one element at the bottom, so it should be easy to use it.

For instance, suppose the order is given by `/*/userorder/@by` and `@by` contains the value matching a `key` element, you can do this:

```
<xsl:sort select="key[. = /*/userorder/@by]/following-sibling::*[1]" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still clumsy at this because I just started learning today. I guess my final question is this: If I want to sort by an already given list that's _only_ Song IDs, how do I do this?

Comment: @user3491271 that is not as trivial to answer as one might expect as it depends on how you receive this list (comma separated?, node set?, variable?, part of source structure?), the XSLT version you use etc. You should best [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with clear well-formed input, expected output, current output and your (partially working) XSLT so far.

Comment: @user3491271: ps, if my answer helped you, feel free to upvote and accept it as answer. If you just started learning today, I think you are already doing quite well! A good tutorial video [on XSLT can be found here](http://www.maxfeel.org/tutorials-list/pluralsight-xslt-2-0-and-1-0-foundations-with-dimitre-novatchev_1v174.html), saving you loads of trial-and-error problems. Happy coding!